# IIS 7.5 site redirects to SSL

Tags: iis, iis-7, iis-7.5

We have our domain name hosted at godaddy and tonight we changed the IP address that maps to that domain. The IP is at a different server from what it used to be. I do not have an SSL cert set up and do not have the website configured to require SSL. When I point to the site from on the server (www.fit-track.net), it works great and goes over http. But when I hit the site from any other machine on the Internet (from my home, my boss's house, etc), it immediately redirects to https (SSL) and blows up because there is not ssl cert configured.

Here is a collage of screenshots so you can see how my IIS 7.5 site is set up. Any ideas? Also it concerns me that there's a little question mark icon next to my website: "Default Web Site". I don't think I need those other bindings: net.tcp, net.pipe, net.m.., msmq -- should I delete those?

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure that questions like this are on-topic here. But why don't you you disable/turn-off the sites that you are not using. Then when you find out which one is active use the edit button and ensure that Require SSL Certificate is not selected.

Comment: Sounds to me like DNS -- Your site is not listening on SSL/443, unless there is another site in this IIS that **is** listening on 443, you would not see a certificate warning, you would get a Cannot establish connection error. **What does the certificate warning say the certificate is issued to?** I would guess that the DNS changes have not fully propagated and you are not being sent to where you think you are. Try `ping` the website to get the IP address it is resolving to.

Comment: This was stupid on me. The app I inherited was doing the redirect in the code and I didn't realize it. All fixed now. Sorry everyone. :-(

Answer (score 0):

This was stupid on me. The app I inherited was doing the redirect in the code and I didn't realize it. All fixed now. Sorry everyone. :-(